# pandas set and use new value of line before

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reuse a pandas column value of a line and reusing this value for all the following lines.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                'B' : [2,3,4,5,6,7]})
df.loc[df.A < df.B, 'C'] = df.B.shift(1)

print(df)
```

gives me:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  2  NaN
1  2  3  2.0
2  3  4  3.0
3  4  5  4.0
4  5  6  5.0
5  6  7  6.0
```

but what I actually want is:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  2  NaN
1  2  3  2.0
2  3  4  2.0
3  4  5  2.0
4  5  6  2.0
5  6  7  2.0
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: why not set `C =2` and then shift it?

Comment: You may want to also include sample data and expected output for rows where `df.A >= df.B`, otherwise you're likely going to get answers that don't fully address your issue.

Comment: What do you want the value to be if A >= B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use idxmax. If the condition is True, get the most recent value in column C, else C = A * B.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],'B' : [2,3,4,5,6,7]})
df['C'] = df['A'] * df['B']
df['C'] = np.where(df.A < df.B, df.loc[(df.A < df.B).idxmax(), 'C'], df.C)

    A   B   C
0   1   2   2
1   2   3   2
2   3   4   2
3   4   5   2
4   5   6   2
5   6   7   2
```

Comment: perfect, exactly I was looking for!

Comment: @user3113106, thats great

Answer (score 0):

SuperStew is correct here; maybe like this:

```
df['C'] = 2
df['C'] = df['C'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. What I want is to get the value from the line before if a particular condition is met.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                'B' : [2,3,4,5,6,7]})
df['C'] = df['A'] * df['B']
df.loc[df.A < df.B, 'C'] = df['C'].shift(1)
    print(df)
```

for instance:

```
   A  B     C
0  1  2   2.0
1  2  3   2.0 # if A<B take the value from C from line above
2  3  4   2.0 # if A is still < B take again the value from C from
3  4  5   2.0 # line above (which originally was 2 lines above)
4  5  6   2.0 # and so on
5  6  7   2.0
```

but what I get is:

```
   A  B     C
0  1  2   NaN
1  2  3   2.0
2  3  4   6.0
3  4  5  12.0
4  5  6  20.0
5  6  7  30.0
```